# Symfony2 app deployment with HWIOAuth and Capifony

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony, hwioauthbundle

After some days I deploy manually a SF2 app, I wrote a Capifony script to automate app deployment.

But the deployment crash with this error :

```
** [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
** The child node "firewall_name" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured.
** Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
*** [RuntimeException]
*** An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Everything work fine on my local environment and when I deploy manually.

I never success to deploy this app, so there is no cache.

I don't understand.

Comment: where did you configure HWI?

Comment: In the `app/config/config.yml` file.

Comment: Is it imported inside the config_prod.yml?

Comment: @Koalabaerchen Yes it is

Comment: Just find a solution, it's because of my Capifony configuration which declared `config_prod.yml` as "shared_files" so by default when the application is deployed for the first time, the file is empty. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So it wasn't imported :) Glad I could serve you as a debug duck and point you in the right direction